# How to respect the order of an array in a PostgreSQL select sentence

Tags: arrays, postgresql, sql-order-by, postgresql-12, array-agg

This is my (extremely simplified) product table and some test data.

```sql
drop table if exists product cascade;

create table product (
  product_id  integer not null,
  reference   varchar,
  price       decimal(13,4),
  
  primary key (product_id)
);

insert into product (product_id, reference, price) values 
(1001, 'MX-232',    100.00),
(1011, 'AX-232',     20.00),
(1003, 'KKK 11',     11.00),
(1004, 'OXS SUPER',   0.35),
(1005, 'ROR-MOT',   200.00),
(1006, '234PPP',     30.50),
(1007, 'T555-NS',   110.25),
(1008, 'LM234-XS',  101.20),
(1009, 'MOTOR-22',   12.50),
(1010, 'MOTOR-11',   30.00),
(1002, 'XUL-XUL1',   40.00);
```

I real life, listing product columns is a taught task, full of joins, case-when-end clauses, etc. On the other hand, there is a large number of queries to be fulfilled, as products by brand, featured products, products by title, by tags, by range or price, etc.

I don't want to repeat and maintain the complex product column listings every time I perform a query so, my current approach is breaking query processes in two tasks:

- encapsulate the query in functions of type `select_products_by_xxx()`, that return `product_id` arrays, properly selected and ordered.
- encapsulate all the product column complexity in a unique function `list_products()` that takes a `product_id array` as a parameter.
- execute `select * from list_products(select_products_by_xxx())` to obtain the desired result for every `xxx` function.

For example, to select `product_id` in reverse order (in case this was any meaningful select for the application), a function like this would do the case.

```sql
create or replace function select_products_by_inverse () 
returns int[]
as $$
  select 
    array_agg(product_id order by product_id desc)  
  from 
    product;
$$ language sql;
```

It can be tested to work as

```sql
select * from select_products_by_inverse();

select_products_by_inverse                              |
--------------------------------------------------------|
{1011,1010,1009,1008,1007,1006,1005,1004,1003,1002,1001}|
```

To encapsulate the "listing" part of the query I use this function (again, extremely simplified and without any join or case for the benefit of the example).

```sql
create or replace function list_products (
    tid int[]
) 
returns table (
  id        integer,
  reference varchar,
  price     decimal(13,4)
)
as $$
  select
    product_id,
    reference,
    price
  from
    product
  where
    product_id = any (tid);
$$ language sql;
```

It works, but does not respect the order of products in the passed array.

```sql
select * from list_products(select_products_by_inverse());

id  |reference|price   |
----|---------|--------|
1001|MX-232   |100.0000|
1011|AX-232   | 20.0000|
1003|KKK 11   | 11.0000|
1004|OXS SUPER|  0.3500|
1005|ROR-MOT  |200.0000|
1006|234PPP   | 30.5000|
1007|T555-NS  |110.2500|
1008|LM234-XS |101.2000|
1009|MOTOR-22 | 12.5000|
1010|MOTOR-11 | 30.0000|
1002|XUL-XUL1 | 40.0000|
```

So, the problem is I am passing a custom ordered array of `product_id` but the `list_products()` function does not respect the order inside the array.

Obviously, I could include an `order by` clause in `list_products()`, but remember that the ordering must be determined by the `select_products_by_xxx()` functions to keep the `list_products()` unique.

Any idea?

---

EDIT

@adamkg solution is simple and works: adding a universal order by clause like this:

```sql
order by array_position(tid, product_id);
```

However, this means to ordering products twice: first inside `select_products_by_xxx()` and then inside `list_products()`.

An `explain` exploration renders the following result:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                            |
----------------------------------------------------------------------|
Sort  (cost=290.64..290.67 rows=10 width=56)                          |
  Sort Key: (array_position(select_products_by_inverse(), product_id))|
  ->  Seq Scan on product  (cost=0.00..290.48 rows=10 width=56)       |
        Filter: (product_id = ANY (select_products_by_inverse()))     |
```

Now I am wondering if there is any other better approach to reduce cost, keeping separability between functions.

I see two promising strategies:

- As for the `explain` clause and the issue itself, it seems that an complete scan of table `product` is being done inside `list_products()`. As there may be thousands of products, a better approach would be to scan the passed array instead.
- The `xxx` functions can be refactored to return `setof int` instead of `int[]`. However, a set cannot be passed as a function parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For long arrays you typically get (much!) more efficient query plans with unnesting the array and joining to the main table. In simple cases, this even preserves the original order of the array without adding `ORDER BY`. Rows are processed in order. But there are no guarantees and the order may be broken with more joins or with parallel execution etc. To be sure, add [**`WITH ORDINALITY`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION list_products (tid int[])  -- VARIADIC?
  RETURNS TABLE (
   id        integer,
   reference varchar,
   price     decimal(13,4)
   )
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE AS
$func$
  SELECT product_id, p.reference, p.price
  FROM   unnest(tid) WITH ORDINALITY AS t(product_id, ord)
  JOIN   product p USING (product_id)  -- LEFT JOIN ?
  ORDER  BY t.ord
$func$;
```

Fast, simple, safe.  See:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)
- [Join against the output of an array unnest without creating a temp table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217557/join-against-the-output-of-an-array-unnest-without-creating-a-temp-table/12218595#12218595)

You might want to throw in the modifier [`VARIADIC`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS), so you can call the function with an array *or* a list of IDs (max 100 items by default). See:

- [Return rows matching elements of input array in plpgsql function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978310/return-rows-matching-elements-of-input-array-in-plpgsql-function/17978831#17978831)
- [Call a function with composite type as argument from native query in jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56847285/call-a-function-with-composite-type-as-argument-from-native-query-in-jpa/56848446#56848446)
- [Function to select column values by comparing against comma separated list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52791715/function-to-select-column-values-by-comparing-against-comma-separated-list/52794191#52794191)

I would declare `STABLE` [function volatility](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html).

You might use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN` to make sure that *all* given IDs are returned - with NULL values if a row with given ID has gone missing.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=eb8867eff44be24a0a955d6aa7ca896f)*

Note a **subtle logic difference with duplicates** in the array. While `product_id` is `UNIQUE` ...

- unnest + left join returns exactly one row for every given ID - preserving duplicates in the given IDs if any.
- `product_id = any (tid)` folds duplicates. (One of the reasons it typically results in more expensive query plans.)

If there are no dupes in the given array, there is no difference. If there can be duplicates and you *want* to fold them, your task is ambiguous, as it's undefined which position to keep.

Comment: Excellent piece of advice, as always @erwin-brandstetter. Thank you so much

Comment: @coterobarros: I added a few more feature that might be of interest.

Comment: @coterobarros: And some logic subtleties.

Comment: Yes, I had noticed the folding behaviour of any with duplicates, as I tested it manually. However, the real case should be always free of product duplicates, except for a human error while writing down a query.

Comment: Regarding the `STABLE` function meta tag... what if the product table does not change but any of the joined tables (group prices, discount rules, texts), change? In this case the same input (integer array) would produce a different result by columns.

Comment: @coterobarros: Still volatility `STABLE`. The function sees a consistent snapshot of the database and always returns the same output for the same input within the same statement. (And it does not modify data.) I added a link above to details in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

You're very close, all you need to add is `ORDER BY array_position(tid, product_id)`.

```
testdb=# create or replace function list_products (
    tid int[]
) 
returns table (
  id        integer,
  reference varchar,
  price     decimal(13,4)
)
as $$
  select
    product_id,
    reference,
    price
  from
    product
  where
    product_id = any (tid)
-- add this:
order by array_position(tid, product_id);
$$ language sql;
CREATE FUNCTION
testdb=# select * from list_products(select_products_by_inverse());
  id  | reference |  price   
------+-----------+----------
 1011 | AX-232    |  20.0000
 1010 | MOTOR-11  |  30.0000
 1009 | MOTOR-22  |  12.5000
 1008 | LM234-XS  | 101.2000
 1007 | T555-NS   | 110.2500
 1006 | 234PPP    |  30.5000
 1005 | ROR-MOT   | 200.0000
 1004 | OXS SUPER |   0.3500
 1003 | KKK 11    |  11.0000
 1002 | XUL-XUL1  |  40.0000
 1001 | MX-232    | 100.0000
(11 rows)
```

Comment: Wow! Great @adamkg!